# How to prevent Sybase from eliminating spaces in a characters fields

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I am facing this issue on sybase.

```
update tst_table set col1 = 'abc  '
```

the result will be

> abc

Sybase will automaticly eliminate the spaces. However I am migrating, so I cannot add the spaces manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change `tst_table.col1` from varchar type to char type. Varchar always truncate spaces but char left spaces to all gap for example string `abc` with 2 spaces. You can also use `text` type to store whole string with spaces.

```
TYPE         VALUE   
-------------------------
varchar(10)  'abc'
char(10)     'abc       ' <----------- 3 chars abc + 7 spaces 
text         'abc  '
```

Below code modify column datatype to char(10)

```
alter table  tst_table
    modify col1 char(10) null
```

As **[documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.commands/html/commands/commands6.htm)** said

> You cannot modify a column to either text or image datatype.

---

One more solution is to use **[reverse](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1510/html/iqrefbb/CHDJAIDE.htm)** function. For example you have a table `tab`:

```
create table tab
(
  var varchar(100)    
)
```

and insert data should be:

```
insert into tab
select reverse('abc  ')
```

if you make select

```
select var from tab
```

you will see the data is

```
'  cba'
```

so should take data like this

```
select reverse(var) from tab
```

But it will work only for strings like `'abc   '` but it doesn't work for strings `'   abc'` and  `'   abc   '`.

Comment: parado the problem in my case that I need one space 'abc ' but there are data has different length like 'abcdef' so if I convert the column to char(6) the result will be 'abcdef ' which is acceptable but for abc wil be 'abc      ' and thats very bad. Do you have a solution?

Comment: @Moudiz I think there is no simple way to do it, why you need space after the string? Maybe we will find another way?

Comment: @Moudiz I've added to my answer description of `text` type please consider it.

Comment: parado , in my java application I am writing "From " bla bla "to " bla bla  so the from and to should contain spaces.

Comment: @Moudiz Did you check `text` type as I said ?

Comment: its a good solution for the spaces. but its bad if there are indexes, (and I had to spent an hour to  fix data conversion in my application)

Comment: @Moudiz hehe, long time :) do you need index? I have one more idea.

Comment: parado.. well for now it seems things are good, but I would like to learn new ways. :)

Comment: @Moudiz I've added one more solution

Comment: update t1 set col1 = select reverse ('  abc') is this the right way how to update it ?

Comment: @Moudiz That way: `update t1 set col1 = select reverse (col1) `

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37323/discussion-between-moudiz-and-parado)

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I solved my problem. In my java application, I need to have a column containing `"From "` bla bla and a column containing `"to "` bla bla.
The varchar datatype will eliminate the spaces, for char datatype if I assigned char(5),
 I'll have multiple trailing spaces `"to    "`

Those empty additional spaces are a problem. As parado mentioned, I cannot modify a column to be text datatype, so I created a backup table, then I dropped the original table. After dropping it, I created the original table from the backup but with 'text' column.

With this approach, I was able to have a column with spaces. But the downside was, one of the columns needed to be in an index, and as you know you can't have indexes on a text datatype.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to change the datatype for the columns that are affected, to one that handles spaces in the way that you expect.

Here is more information about how different datatypes handle trailing spaces.

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36271.1550/html/blocks/blocks45.htm

Comment: Micheal the link was confusing, can you please send me a correct one

Comment: Sorry about that, I fixed the link.